# Adobe-Brackets XML/XSLT Code Completion

Tags: xslt, code-completion, adobe-brackets, code-hinting

I'm looking for guide / example / "how to" to working with XSLT language.

With combine all HTML language and more few XSLT tag and function, I can use language default as HTML..

Can I only add (does not replace or remove default code-hint) few tag, attribute, function etc. of XSLT language base on HTML language ?

These some tag and attribute I collected (and changed for my work):

TAGs:

```
{
    "xsl:apply-templates":  { "attributes": ["mode", "select"] },
    "xsl:attribute":        { "attributes": ["name"] },
    "xsl:call-template":    { "attributes": ["name"] },
    "xsl:choose":           { "attributes": [] },
    "xsl:copy":             { "attributes": ["use-attribute-sets"] },
    "xsl:for-each":         { "attributes": ["select"] },
    "xsl:if":               { "attributes": ["test"] },
    "xsl:otherwise":        { "attributes": [""] },
    "xsl:param":            { "attributes": ["name", "select"] },
    "xsl:sort":             { "attributes": ["case-order", "data-type", "order", "select"] },
    "xsl:template":         { "attributes": ["match", "mode", "name"] },
    "xsl:text":             { "attributes": ["disable-output-escaping"] },
    "xsl:value-of":         { "attributes": ["disable-output-escaping", "select"] },
    "xsl:variable":         { "attributes": ["name", "select"] },
    "xsl:when":             { "attributes": ["test"] },
    "xsl:with-param":       { "attributes": ["name", "select"] }

}
```

ATTRIBUTEs:

```
{    "xsl:apply-templates/mode":  { "attribOption": ["Render", "Copy"] },
    "xsl:apply-templates/select":  { "attribOption": ["@*|node()"] },

    "xsl:attribute/name":        { "attribOption": ["class", "style"] },

    "xsl:copy/use-attribute-sets": { "attribOption": ["@|*node"] },

    "xsl:if/test":          { "attribOption": ["count() &gt; 0"] },

    "xsl:sort":             { "attribOption": ["case-order", "data-type", "order", "select"] },

    "xsl:template/match":   { "attribOption": ["@*|node()"] },
    "xsl:template/mode":    { "attribOption": ["Render", "Copy"] },

    "xsl:text/disable-output-escaping":     { "attribOption": ["yes","no"], "type": "boolean" },
    "xsl:value-of/disable-output-escaping": { "attribOption": ["yes","no"], "type": "boolean" },

    "xsl:when/test":        { "attribOption": ["count() &gt; 0"] }
}
```